# Why does performance degrade when using a non-indexed field in the SELECT clause?

Tags: sql-server

Consider these three queries:

```
select sampleno from sample
    where markupdate > '1/1/2010'

select sampleno, markupdate from sample
    where markupdate > '1/1/2010'

select sampleno, markuptime from sample
    where markupdate > '1/1/2010'
```

`sampleno` and `markupdate` are indexed fields (`sampleno` is the primary key)

`markuptime` is not indexed

Queries 1 and 2 take about 1 second to run (returning 237K rows).  Query 3 is still running after 3 minutes.

Why would the inclusion of a non-indexed field in the SELECT clause cause such a performance degradation?

This is a SQL 6.5 database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A table's data (basically: all columns) is stored in a **clustered index**.  A clustered index is a binary tree that allows a binary search on the indexed column(s).  It is special (clustered) in that it contains all other columns at the leaf level.  Usually, the clustered index is also the primary key.  In your case, it's:

```
(sampleno) include (markupdate, markuptime, ...)
```

A **non-clustered index** contains the indexed column(s) and (at the leaf level) the clustered index.  When you use a non-clustered index, the database has to look up all the other columns in the clustered index.  That process is called a **lookup**.  In your case, the non-clustered index on `(markupdate)` is:

```
(markupdate) include (sampleno)
```

This index contains all data for a query on `markupdate, sampleno`.  The technical term for such an index is a **covering index**.  But when you add `markuptime` to the query, the index is no longer covering.  It has to look up the value for `markuptime` in the clustered index. And lookups are expansive.

Only your third query requires lookups.  And that's why your third query is slower.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to the query to temporarily include markuptime in an index or must I create an index for the table that includes markuptime?

Comment: You can add an INCLUDE to include MarkupTime on your non-clustered index on MarkUpdate this will give you a "covering index" for the third query. (Nevermind, you could do this if you had a more recent version of SQL... I guess just add MarkupTime as another column to your MarkUpdate index.)